# Using 50 threads in JMeter but application logs out

Tags: spring, jsf, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin, badboy

I have test cases properly created and compiled in JMeter using the badboy. I ran the test for 1 Thread 1 ramp-up period and 1 Loop count (screenshot of the settings are attached with the query) and the test runs completely fine. Now I increased the Threads to 20 and it runs fine but when I start increasing it more like 50 or 80 threads then after few test cases the script logs out. I am testing an application based on JSF and I have taken care of the faces issue where the ViewState have to be passed to every next request being sent so the session is maintained. The problem here is that when the number of threads increases the application takes me to the login screen after a few steps.

I have also tried by un-ticking the option "Delay Thread creation until needed"
Kindly suggest a solution

JMeter Version: 3.2

Thanks and regards,
Prasad Iyer

[Thread Setting for 1 user][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcVub.jpg

[Thread Setting for 80 users][2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ4gA.jpg

Comment: What d'ya mean by "script logs out"?

Comment: Not enough information to suggest any solution.

Comment: By script logs out I mean that if there are 30 test cases in the script and if I run the script for only one Thread(user) then all of them run as expected but when I increase the threads to 50 then only the first two test cases work rest all just show the login in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Blind shot: add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to handle [JSESSIONID](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html) and other cookies (in some installations you will need [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier))

If it is already there (or does not help) inspect your application under test logs, most probably you will find some errors there (you might need to increase logs verbosity)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, by test logs do you mean Jmeter.log because if I try to debug the "view results tree" there is no error that I get. HTTP Cookie Manager is already included to maintain the JSESSIONID
I will try using HTTP URL Re-writing and get back

Comment: As suggested I tried using HTTP URL Re-write but it still logs out
Find attached the screenshot of HTTP URL Re-Write
URL Re-Write: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u5Ga.jpg
Sample value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQAbH.jpg